# passing bash arguments into sed to delete lines

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm trying to write a `bash` function which will take all the arguments sent to it and push them through `sed` to delete lines in a file that match the arguments. A use case example:

```
to_delete get the trash
```

I can get it to "almost" work like this:

```
function to_delete() { sed -i -e "/$@/d" /tmp/testfile; }
```

The problem with this is it will only work if I send a single command line argument:

```
to_delete get
```

If I send more than one it returns this error:

```
sed: 1: "/get": unterminated regular expression
```

It will also work if I throw quotes around the arguments:

```
to_delete "get the trash"
```

But I'd rather not have to do that.

Any ideas on how to get this working? Thanks.

Comment: Having quotes seems like a reasonable approach. It's a single argument with 3 words, not 3 separate arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have with $@ is that it expands in separately quoted arguments.

You could in theory use $* instead because this hasn't the feature.

**BUT** $* will have the arguments separated by the first character of IFS (usually a space).

So the trouble is if you do something:

```
to_delete foo   bar baz
```

The pattern will look like:

```
/foo bar baz/d
```

(Only one space).

All this mess is avoided if you use a quoted argument, nothing wrong with this.

Answer (score 0):

Quotes is a good option. If you still insist in having this, one option would be something like this:

```
function to_delete() { sed -i -e "/`echo $@`/d" /tmp/testfile; }
```

The problem was that `$@` get separated into several arguments. This have several problems, though, for instance, the search term having the character '`/`', for instance.

Comment: This will also have the problem of not preserving the number of spaces/tabs whatever IFS is set to thing.

Comment: You can use an alternate delimiter chosen to be a character that doesn't appear in the file. An example using colons: `"\:$(echo $@):d`