# Line deleting trouble in bash: passing user-input to sed vs to grep?

Tags: bash, sed, grep, msys

Bashing trouble in MSYS: The following simple function should delete all lines that match user-input string `$kwd`.

```
function delnote () {
   read kwd
   sed -e "/$kwd/d" -i ~/notes.txt
}
```

Instead, I keep getting *"sed -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression"* errors. Why?

I'm new to both bash and sed (and MSYS), so I'm not sure whether this is an issue of passing variables to sed or using quotes the wrong way (I've effortlessly tried replacing `""` with `''` in many variations). I tried using [the function provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108850/passing-bash-arguments-into-sed-to-delete-lines) instead of my own, but still got the same error.

In case this is an issue of misplacing quotes, then what's the difference between how sed and grep handle user input in bash? (As opposed to sed, using `'"$*"'` in a grep function does work.)

Thanks for any help and explanations!

Comment: Try running the script with `bash -x path/to/script.sh` or add the command `set -x` at the beginning of the script. It enables some kind of debug mode, and might reveal important information.

Comment: Okay, this is really odd, but it started to work. I can't pass my search word directly, though (as in `delnote keyword`). It keeps waiting for user input, so I need to provide it on a separate line after launching the function. Thanks for the `-x` though, It's a very useful thing to know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I yet seemed to mess something up when copying [the solution linked above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108850/passing-bash-arguments-into-sed-to-delete-lines%20). Now it works, like this:

```
function delnote () {
  sed -e "/`echo $*`/d" -i ~/notes.txt;
}
```

As a non-coder and n00b, I'd still appreciate any explanations as to what was wrong with my initial version, though. Plus, why does `echo` seem to fix the issue here? Thanks.

Comment: The echo is useless (you can just use $* directly). $* is a string of all args passed to the function. So in this case, you are actually using the args. In your first example, you are reading from stdin, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've removed the unneccessary "echo" and did some reading on bash stdin etc.